# how to optimize code like reduce code with same functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
let response = {};
var filters = {
  topfeaturedandotherfields: req.body.topfeaturedandotherfields,
};

if (req.body.minprice && req.body.maxprice && req.body.brandName) {
  var filters = {
    $and: [
      { brandName: { $in: req.body.brandName } },
      { topfeaturedandotherfields: req.body.topfeaturedandotherfields },
      { salePrice: { $gte: req.body.minprice, $lte: req.body.maxprice } },
    ],
  };

  var result = await productService.getAllProductofhomepage(
    filters,
    req.body.ordername,
    req.body.orderby
  );
} else {
  if (req.body.minprice && req.body.maxprice) {
    var filters = {
      $and: [
        { topfeaturedandotherfields: req.body.topfeaturedandotherfields },
        { salePrice: { $gte: req.body.minprice, $lte: req.body.maxprice } },
      ],
    };

    var result = await productService.getAllProductofhomepage(
      filters,
      req.body.ordername,
      req.body.orderby
    );
  }
  if (req.body.brandName) {
    var filters = {
      $and: [
        { brandName: { $in: req.body.brandName } },
        { topfeaturedandotherfields: req.body.topfeaturedandotherfields },
      ],
    };

    var result = await productService.getAllProductofhomepage(
      filters,
      req.body.ordername,
      req.body.orderby
    );
  }
}

if (req.body.limit == true)
  var result = await productService.getAllProductofhomepagewithlimit(filters);
else if (req.body.minprice || req.body.maxprice || req.body.brandName) {
} else {
  var result = await productService.getAllProductofhomepage(
    filters,
    req.body.ordername,
    req.body.orderby
  );
}

if (result.length > 0) {
  response = {
    message: "Home page products successfully retrieved",
    error: false,
    data: result,
  };
} else {
  response = {
    message: "Faild to get products",
    error: true,
    data: {},
  };
}

res.status(200).json(response);
```

**This code is used to filter like to see top feature and bestseller or min and max price and the brand name also in this code sort by order name which could be price or brand name or category also in ascending and descending order so now you can see this code is like if and else but I want to optimize and reduce code**

Answer (score 1):

You can make this query quite a lot nicer by just dynamically building the query condition instead of breaking the logic into `if/else` blocks:

```
export async function login(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    const response = {};
    let filters = {
        topfeaturedandotherfields: req.body.topfeaturedandotherfields,
    };

    if (req.body.minprice || req.body.maxprice) {
        const saleCond = { };
        if (req.body.minprice) {
            saleCond.$gte = req.body.minprice;
        }
        if (req.body.maxprice) {
            saleCond.$lte = req.body.maxprice;
        }
        filters.salePrice = saleCond
    }

    if (req.body.brandName) {
        filters.brandName = {$in: req.body.brandName}
    }

    let result = [];
    if (req.body.limit == true) {
        result = await productService.getAllProductofhomepagewithlimit(filters)
    } else {
        result = await productService.getAllProductofhomepage(filters, req.body.ordername, req.body.orderby);
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        message: result.length ? 'Home page products successfully retrieved' : 'Failed to get products',
        error: result.length === 0,
        data: result,
    });
}
```

Not only is this much clearer we only removed a redundant DB call that was made in the process.